# Play-Reactivemongo 0.12.0 angular-seed

Tags: angularjs, scala, reactivemongo

While refactoring from ReactiveMongo.0.11.1 to ReactiveMongo 0.12.0 in reference of https://github.com/AhmadMelegy/play-silhouette-reactivemongo-angular-seed compilation failed:

```
 def configure() {
      bind[DB].toInstance 
      {
        import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
        import reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB
        import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
        import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
        import scala.concurrent.Future

        val config = ConfigFactory.load
        val driver = new MongoDriver
        val connection = driver.connection(
          config.getStringList("mongodb.servers"),
          MongoConnectionOptions(),
          Seq()
        )
        connection.database(config.getString("mongodb.db"))
      }
```

How to resolve this issue?

```
required: reactivemongo.api.DB   
found : scala.concurrent.Future[reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB]
```

Comment: See http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/release-details.html#database-resolution, especially *"It’s generally a good practice not to assign the database and collection references to val (even to lazy val), as it’s better to get a fresh reference each time [..]"* - so using DI to resolve the database may not be the most sensible approach here.

Comment: The release notes must be read about the new DB resolution. It's recommanded to first have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

**Not recommended**

You can use `Await` to receive result from the `Future` and bind it.

**Recommended**

Use "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule" 
http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html

Example of configuration:

```
# The default URI
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://someuser:somepasswd@localhost:27017/foo"

# Another one, named with 'bar'
mongodb.bar.uri = "mongodb://someuser:somepasswd@localhost:27017/lorem"
```

Example of code

```
class MyComponent @Inject() (
  val defaultApi: ReactiveMongoApi, // corresponds to 'mongodb.uri'
  @NamedDatabase("bar") val barApi: ReactiveMongoApi // 'mongodb.bar'
) {

}
```

If you need to do your own binding, then just look at this example:
https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/modules/reactivemongo/ReactiveMongoModule.scala

Comment: Hi Andriy Kuba,sorry for the late rply,as per your solution I had tried below,still something wrong ,please look into this issuepackage controllers
  class indexController @Inject()(val defaultApi: ReactiveMongoApi,
      @NamedDatabase("silhouette")) extends Controller
    with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {
 def userdao = new UserDAOImpl(reactiveMongoApi) at config file:mongodb.uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/silhouette"